# How to make dark theme for website with javascript

Tags: javascript, web, google-web-designer

Can you suggest a plugin or library for the dark theme feature I want to add to my website? (no optimization problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have several options, and i will list them right below, though i really recommend doing it by yourself if you have the time and resources, it will look better and fill much more natural than using a library (that usually just changes the `mix-blend-mode` in your css.

[darkmode.js](https://darkmodejs.learn.uno/) - I believe that they are the most known one.

[nighly.js](https://github.com/Fcmam5/nightly.js) - they claim to have zero-dependencies, this could help you be more protected from dependencies vulnerabilities.

[backgroundcheck.js](https://github.com/kennethcachia/background-check)

[darklight.js](https://github.com/MinhasKamal/DarkLight)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be good
[Darkmode.js](https://github.com/sandoche/Darkmode.js)